# Why does NSLookup provides DNS resolution but also says "No answer"?

Tags: kubernetes, nslookup

When I performed a `nslookup` in a Pod within my k8s cluster for a Service name I get the following result:

```
Server:         172.20.0.10
Address:        172.20.0.10:53
 
Name:   app.one.svc.cluster.local
Address: 172.20.40.30
 
*** Can't find app.one.svc.cluster.local: No answer
```

The IP returned `172.20.40.30` is correct but it still says:

```
*** Can't find app.one.svc.cluster.local: No answer
```

I was expecting it to return the IP as it did but not to also get a `No Answer` response.

I didn't get a chance to test with `dig`, `getent` etc. and the issue is unfortunately no longer reproducible at this stage.